# ¿Como genero labels de manera dinamica en mi for each?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Lo que me gustaria hacer es un listado de todas mis imagenes subidas, que estan en un folder de mi aplicacion, dicho folder ya contiene imagenes y quisiera ponerlas en un listado de etiquetas, hasta ahora mi codigo es el siguiente:

Codigo Listado Imagenes:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\NQ054\Videos\Presupuesto_Da\Imagenes\Febrero");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpeg");
string str = "";
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    str = str + ", " + file.Name;
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text=file.ToString();
    labels.Add(label);

}
```

Si lo debugeo si me guarda una imagen por indice en el listado, pero como le hago para que las etiquetas se vean en mi aplicacion, si son 10 imagenes serian 10 etiquetas.

> Actualizacion

Ya me agregue solamente la primera etiquetas, pero lo que quiero es que agregue las 10 que necesito para cada imagen, esas estan en el listado.

Codigo para agregar una etiqueta:

```
this.Controls.Add(labelI);
```

Comment: ¿El texto del `Label` no debería ser el nombre de la imagen?, ¿es para ASP.NET o WInForms?

Comment: @MauricioArias Olave es winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        str = str + ", " + file.Name;
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text=file.ToString();
        this.Controls.Add(label); <<<-----
    }
```

Recuerda tambien que tienes que definirle una **locacion** y tamaño a esos componentes (aunque supongo yo que los Labels adquiriran el mismo tamaño de la imagen).

Comment: Realice los cambios necesarios, pero solo me obtiene el primer nombre de mis imagenes, como se puede agregar todo el listado al controls. si lo hago de forma directa no me lo permite